# Selecting certain lines from a data file

Tags: c++, text-files

I have a datafile of this form:

```
B123 1 3 4
f
g=1
B123 3 4 4
t
z=2
.
.
.
```

What I would like to do is to pick the data from the lines starting with B123;

Here's my attempt:

```
ifstream in("Data");
ofstream out("output");

string x1, x2, x3, x4;
char z[] = "B123";
const char *p;
p=x1.c_str();

while(1)
{
    in>> x1;
    if(!(strcmp(z,p)))
    {
        if((in>>x1>>x2>>x3>>x4))
        {
             output<<x1<<x2<<x3<<x4;
        }
        else
             break;
     }
}

return 0;
```

But, this way, I only get an empty output file. I want to get:

```
B123 1 3 4
B123 3 4 4
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you mixing `std::string` and C-style strings? You can compare two `std::string`s using the `==` operator.

Comment: Unless there's more to the problem than this, my suggestion would be `grep "^B123" your_file`.

Comment: I see, Ok I have no idea what I was doing. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this instead:

```
while(1)
{
    getline(in, x1);
    if (in.eof()) break;
    if (x1.find(z) != string::npos) {
        out << x1 << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: z must be at the begining of the line, turn your comparison '!= string::npos' to '== 0'

Answer (score 4):

Read the lines of the file, find the match for `B123` and if it is found, save that. Pseudocode:

```
while !eof():
   line = file.readlines()
   if "B123" in line:
        cout <<< line << endl
```

Also, I advise you to use `strstr()` instead of `strcmp()`. I guess you only need to find the substring `B123` in the line:

```
// string::substr
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str="We think in generalities, but we live in details.";
                             // quoting Alfred N. Whitehead
  string str2, str3;
  size_t pos;

  str2 = str.substr (12,12); // "generalities"

  pos = str.find("live");    // position of "live" in str
  str3 = str.substr (pos);   // get from "live" to the end

  cout << str2 << ' ' << str3 << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see, so this way I separate the process into two steps. outputting the lines starting with B123, then read the data that I want from the resulting output file. I'll try this. Thank you.

Comment: @stupidity I could give you the code, but it won't make you a better programmer.

Comment: Thank you :p I can use: getline, but then how can I test if the line contains B123? Is there a straightforward way?

Comment: @stupidity I've updated my answer in other to include can you test if the line contains `B123`

Comment: Thanks for your help and valuable suggestions, +1. I had to choose the answer from Michael as the solution since it explicitly does what I was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you define `p` before `x1` is defined.  `p` just equals a blank string because `x1` does too.  Instead, you need to do this:

```
ifstream in("Data");
ofstream out("output");

string x1, x2, x3, x4;
char z[] = "B123";
const char *p;


while(1)
{
    in>> x1;
    p=x1.c_str();
    if(!(strcmp(z,p)))
    {
        if((in>>x1>>x2>>x3>>x4))
        {
             output<<x1<<x2<<x3<<x4;
        }
        else
             break;
     }
}

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First is that you're getting a pointer to the string before the string exists. Every time you read a string, the internal storage could change and invalidate the previous pointer. You need to move the `.c_str()` call to a point after the string is read.

The second problem is that you're using `strcmp` which compares the *entire* string. Try using `strncmp` instead to compare a limited number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

if you read the data just after B123 only to output them, then the following snippet will do

```
ifstream in("data");
ofstream out("out");
string line;
while (getline(in, line)) {
    if (line.length() >= 4 && line.substr(0, 4) == "B123") {
        out << line << "\n";
    }
}
```

if you really need x1, x2 ... for further process, you'll have to add some lines ...